# How to grant Permission to all objects in a database in SQL Server to a database user through query

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, permissions

I am creating multiple database users in SQL Server. Suppose if I create 2 users besides default System Administrator as following.

1. sa(System Administrator)
2. user1
3. user2

I want sa(System Administrator) to grant all permissions such as permission to create table, views etc to user1. And then let user1 to grant permissions to user2. If I do this using SQL Server GUI I need to check a long list of permissions to be granted for each user.

I tried following query but it grants permission on only a single table instead of a database. So if my database has more than 100 tables then I will need to run more than 100 such queries. Therefore can anyone let me know if there is a single query which I can execute to let **sa** to grant permissions to different users on a particular database instead of just a table.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE  ON dbo.table1 TO user1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to grant the permission like

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'username'
```

This will give WRITE permissions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) for every table present in your database.

Comment: Hello,

I tried this above query but its not granting any permission.